# Split a DataFrame by rows containing zero in python pandas

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

Apologies if what I'm asking is very basic and has been answered elsewhere (couldn't find it, but it could be I'm just using the wrong terminology).

I would like to be able to split a DataFrame when a certain amount of successive 0s appears in a column. Let's say I have this DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

idx = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=6, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(6), 'B': [3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=6, freq='D'))
```

```
            A  B
2020-01-01  0  3
2020-01-02  1  2
2020-01-03  2  0
2020-01-04  3  0
2020-01-05  4  1
2020-01-06  5  2
```

What I'd like to arrive at is two DataFrames that are shaped like this:

```
            A  B
2020-01-01  0  3
2020-01-02  1  2

            A  B
2020-01-05  4  1
2020-01-06  5  2
```

I suspect it can be done with `groupby` and possibly a `lambda` (?) but I didn't have any luck trying...

Comment: Hi ! I'd suggest you to post this question in Stack Overflow, it's more a code question than a Data Science one, and there's a huge community answering Pandas questions there

Comment: Do you actually need to store them as new objects (dataframes) or do you need a groupby so you can then do something else to each groupby later?

Comment: That’s actually a good question! I’d like to do some unsupervised clustering of the split frames afterwards, so I suspect new objects? But this is my first time dabbling with pandas :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a not-so-elegant solution, which would however get you to the `groupby` you need :)

```
df2 = df.mask((df['B'] == 0) & ((df['B'].shift(1) == 0) | (df['B'].shift(-1) == 0)))
df2['group'] = (df2['B'].shift(1).isnull() & df2['B'].notnull()).cumsum()
df2[df2['B'].notnull()].groupby('group')
```

If you inspect `df2` (I'm creating a new one just in case you want to have two different ones, but you can perhaps chain the operation if need be), it looks like this now:

```
            A     B     group
2020-01-01  0.0   3.0   1
2020-01-02  1.0   2.0   1
2020-01-03  NaN   NaN   1
2020-01-04  NaN   NaN   1
2020-01-05  4.0   1.0   2
2020-01-06  5.0   2.0   2
```

So, now you can filter out values where `df['B'] is null` (which is essentially the rows where two consecutive 0s appeared in a row), and then groupby this new column `group`.

What happens here is:

```
df.mask((df['B'] == 0) & ((df['B'].shift(1) == 0) | (df['B'].shift(-1) == 0)))
```

If the B value is equal to 0 and either the previous or next one are also equal to zero, hide these rows (replace with NaN via `df.mask()`)

```
df2['group'] = (df2['B'].shift(1).isnull() & df2['B'].notnull()).cumsum()
```

Create an indicator column `group`, just to let Pandas know what to `groupby` (you can also just directly group by that whole expression, I just want to make the step clear). The group is defined as follows: a new group is defined if the previous value of B is Null, and if the current value is not null. Then take the cumulative sum, and this way you get this fabricated "id" to groupby.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive solution - it works, so I accepted it. I'm wondering though if there's a more robust way to formalize the amount of "empty days" to split the DataFrames... like you would do when splitting a string, i.e. simply defining the amount of consecutive empty chars/rows